# json integration with vaadin

Tags: json, vaadin

I would like to inform to forum to get few examples on JSON which works with Vaadin Project.

The Actual Procedure is as shown below

Point 1: We get the Java Objects from Server Point 2: Converting Java Objects into JSON Point 3: Solution Required: How to integrate JSON with Vaadin Project.

Any specific examples to build the required solution will be much appreciated. Kindly revert.

Comment: Could you try to explain a bit more detailed exactly what you are trying to get done in the integration part? Normally you really don't have to or want to touch the Vaadin-generated JSON in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Vaadin is a **server-side** UI framework. That means you anything you do in your application, you do that on the server-side. The client-side widgets (running in browser) are automatically handled by the framework.

That said, you can use any JSON **Java** library you like to read/write JSON objects. A good list of libraries is maintained at http://www.json.org/

As an example, here is a small one of parsing JSON into Java objects with [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) (using Jettison driver) and binding the Java object to [Vaadin Form](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#Forms):

```
// Deserialize the JSON to a Java Bean
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.alias("person", PersonBean.class);
PersonBean person = (PersonBean) xstream
    .fromXML("{person: {name:'John Doe',age:45}}");

// Bind the Java Bean to a Vaadin Form
Form form = new Form();
mainWindow.addComponent(form);
form.setItemDataSource(new BeanItem<PersonBean>(person));
```

Where the *PersonBean* is just a simple Java class:

```
public class PersonBean {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```